# dart #import weirdness in dart editor

Tags: dart

So I have two dart files -- One defines the entry-point Main() and the other is a class I've created.  The Main file #imports dart:html and #sources my class.  My class uses the dart:html namespace, and Dart Editor will display errors if I don't #import it.  However, my class will fail to compile if I #import dart:html since the Main file already does, but compiles fine without the #import.  Is there a way to appease the dart editor, or is this a known issue with how the dart editor resolves namespaces?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should only do the import once and then source your program files from your main file. Something like this:

**main.dart**

```
#import("dart:html");
#source("program.dart");

main() {
   var program = new Program();
   program.run();
}
```

**program.dart**

```
class Program {
   run() {
       var elm = new Element.html("<p>hello world</p>");
       document.body.nodes.add(elm);
   }
}
```

should definitely work.

Comment: Fixed it temporarily, but Dart Editor is still definitely flaky and unpredictable in its design-time checking.

Comment: @w.brian I have not experienced this much with libraries but I agree that sometimes one needs to flip analysis on and off to get it to handle the code correctly. I try to post bugs with it and hopefully it should soon be gone